# Find addresses using Map and Filter functions - Python

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, find

I have to find the IPv4 addresses in a txt file.
The format of the IPv4 addresses is "dotted quad", that is, 4 numbers (0-255) separate by dots(.)

I got this, but my problem is that I have to use **map and filter functions**.

That is what I have

```
def buscarIPv4(file):
    for line in file:
        b=[]
        pattern = re.compile('(\s[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)')
        a = pattern.search(line)        
        pos_texto = line.find(line)
        if a is not None:
            b = a.group(1)
            print(b)
    return
```

Can anyone help me with this? **I have to find IPv4 address in a .txt file using map and filter**

Comment: Can you help us to help you by posting what you've tried first?

Answer (score 0):

"re" is clearly the superior option.

```
import re

ips = re.findall('(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})',open(file).read())
```

But if you can't use that, then you need to break up your file into words and process on the words. Something like this should work:

```
def is_ip(word):
    ds = word.split('.')
    return len(ds)==4 and all(d.isdigit() for d in ds) and all(0<=int(d)<=255 for d in ds)

ips = list(filter(is_ip,open(file).read().split()))
```